# Rake Tasks ERROR : Don't know how to build tasks 'production'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building an app which has a plan model, and a users model. The plan model has_many users, and is responsible for plan details, price etc.

What I'd like to do, is to build a rake tasks which allows me to create 3 plans in heroku. I've been messing around with the code, but keep on getting the error, when I run `heroku run rake db:populate_plans`

```
Don't know how to build task 'production'
```

Here's the code written for it :

```
namespace :db do
  desc "fill in plans"
  task populate_plans: :production do

    Plan.create!(name: "Professional", max_phone_numbers: "5", max_minutes: "500", price: "49.95" )

    Plan.create!(  name: "Small Business", max_phone_numbers: "10", max_minutes: "1000", price: "99.95" )       

    Plan.create!( name: "Office", max_phone_numbers: "25", max_minutes: "2000", price: "149.95" )        

    end
  end
```

Any guidance on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your task is named `db:populate_plans`...

Comment: ...wow that was stupid of me. Changed to heroku run rake db:populate_plans, but now I get the error : don't know how run task 'production'. Thoughts?

Comment: 1. Why not to use seeds? 2. Did you try to change `:production` to `:environment`?

Comment: I hadn't heard of seeds before -- Just found this http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data . Thanks for the heads up, I'll look into this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
namespace :db do
  desc "fill in plans"
  task :populate_plans => :environment do
    Plan.create!(name: "Professional", max_phone_numbers: "5", max_minutes: "500", price: "49.95" )
    Plan.create!(  name: "Small Business", max_phone_numbers: "10", max_minutes: "1000", price: "99.95" )       
    Plan.create!( name: "Office", max_phone_numbers: "25", max_minutes: "2000", price: "149.95" )        
  end
end
```

now run rake db:populate_plans RAILS_ENV=production

Comment: Aand that did the trick! There's one problem though -- it seems like the name, max_phone_numbers, and max_minutes etc did not register. The plan was created, but it's values are nil. What are your thoughts as to why this would happen?

Comment: try in console to create plan, what happen check it. 
also try this - Plan.create(:name => "Professional", :max_phone_number => 5, :max_minutes => 500, :price => 49.95 )